# How to configure resource adapter in JBoss AS 7 with ActiveMQ 5.7.0

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic

I need to configure a resource adapter in JBoss AS 7 with ActiveMQ 5.7.0.

Comment: See this [link](http://blog.coffeebeans.at/?p=230)

Comment: have you succeeded with this?